# To create AMI of the instance in a region(Mumbai) different from AWS Lamda(Singapore) located

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, python, amazon-ami

I am using AWS Lamda to create AMI's on daily basis for my ec2 prod instance. All my infra setup in in mumbai region but **aws doesn't support Lamda functionality in mumbai region yet.**

So, I choosen Singapore region to setup Lamda. I fallowed the links [create-AMI](https://gist.github.com/bkozora/724e01903a9ad481d21e) and [cleanup-ami](https://gist.github.com/bkozora/d4f1cf0e5cf26acdd377) to create and delete ami's after retention period.

However, this worked if I have the instance also in singapore region with the specified tags in the code.

My question here is, how could I achieve, to fetch instances in the mumbai region and create ami.?(Lamda is in Singapore region)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you create an AWS client in AWS Lambda, it will use the same region in which the Lambda function is running.

It is possible to change the region which the clients are using. This is done when constructing the client. The following code will set the desired region.

Javascript (Node):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ region: 'ap-south-1' });
```

Python (boto3):

```
client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    region = 'ap-south-1'
)
```

Comment: I am pretty new to python boto. This Worked. Thanks